# Jmeter maven plugin - how do you configure the log4j configuration?

Tags: jmeter

I'd like to configure the logging in JMeter via the log4j2 configuration file.

But I am using the JMeter maven plugin to run our performance tests.

Which means I have to specify the configurations for jmeter via properties in the maven pom.xml file.

There is a `logsDirectory` property and a `overrideRootLogLevel` property, but I see no way to customize the log4j2 properties. Maybe I should set the customizations as system props?

How do I make changes to the log4j properties when I am using the JMeter maven plugin?

Comment: Did you tried adding log4j2.xml into the `<confFilesDirectory>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to do it.

In the maven plugin config, I added this:

```
<jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
  <arguments>
    <argument>-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\jmeter-log4j2.xml</argument>
```

And that works in my case because I will always launch my test from the source folder. But there's probably a more elegant way to do it.